# How do I update User object at scale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdata

My Ruby on Rails application has 100,000,000 users. I have a column on the model called 'data' which is a JSON field which contains a fairly small JSON object which I would like to backup by saving to a new field.

If I had 1,000 users I could simply run:

```
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
    user.data_backup = user.data
    user.save
end
```

and save the existing data to a new column. However, this could potentially take forever with so many users. What's the proper and/or most efficient way to update any field on the model at scale when I have 100,000,000+ users?

Comment: If you have 100MM users I'm not sure why you'd want to do this in the first place. This will immediately double the storage requirements of your table. I'd suggest creating a secondary table with the backup data so it's not necessary to load this each time *any* user record is fetched. Are you intending to create some kind of versioning system here so you can undo or revert changes?

Answer (score 2):

For a large number of records, try to use find_in_batchs method

```
User.find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |users|
  users.each do |user|
    user.data_backup = user.data
    user.save
  end
end
```

Comment: find_each will save you a block here :-)

Comment: This will trigger the save call back, use update_all in instead may be better

Answer (score 0):

Could be done in SQL:

```
sql = "UPDATE users SET data_backup = data"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

or `update_all`:

```
User.update_all('data_backup = data')
```

Comment: Your alternate form is not going to work. `data` is a variable that's not defined, and even if it was, you're setting every single user to the same value. The first `update_all` is correct.

Comment: I didn't write the alternative. I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

We had a scenario where we have to iterate over a large set of records and invoke respective notification.

```
User.all.each do |user|
  NewsMailer.weekly(user).deliver_now
end
```

The above code would satisfactory achieve our end goal.
But this approach becomes increasingly impractical as the table size increases, since User.all.each instructs Active Record to fetch the entire table in a single pass, build a model object per row, and then keep the entire array of model objects in memory. Indeed, if we have a large number of records, the entire collection may exceed the amount of memory available.

**A scenario where you have to perform the bulk update**, Rails provides methods that address this problem by dividing records into memory-friendly batches for processing.

1. **find_each, retrieves a batch of records and then yields each record to the block individually as a model.**

   ```
    User.find_each(batch_size: 5000) do |user|
         NewsMailer.weekly(user).deliver_now
    end
   ```

   or

**Another example would be if you wanted multiple workers handling the same processing queue**. You could have each worker handle 10000 records by setting the appropriate :start and :finish options on each worker.

```
User.find_each(start: 2000, finish: 10000) do |user|
  NewsMailer.weekly(user).deliver_now
end
```

2. **find_in_batches, retrieves a batch of records and then yields the entire batch to the block as an array of models.**
   The find_in_batches method is similar to find_each, since both retrieve batches of records. The difference is that find_in_batches yields batches to the block as an array of models, instead of individually.

   User.find_in_batches do |user|

   ```
     NewsMailer.weekly(user).deliver_now
   ```

   end